# Should Doxygen documentation be placed before include guards?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

Should Doxygen documentation be placed before or after include guards; before or inside a namespace?

Assume the header contains the declaration of a single class (`context`) and this is what I am documenting here.

```
#ifndef CONTEXT_HPP
#define CONTEXT_HPP

#include <string>    

/**
 * The application context interface.
 */
namespace test {
    class context { ... };
}
```

Comment: File documentation should appear before include guards, other before the documented elements (namespace, class, methods, ...).

Comment: they wont spoil the building of the app? In other words, are comments removed before inclusion and compile?

Comment: Comments are comments, they have no effect on compilation.

Comment: @g-makulik Why before include guards? It might make more work for the preprocessor.

Comment: @g-makulik they dont have an effect on the preprocessor either?

Comment: @JoshuaMN They don't have ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How come? Doesn't the preprocessor have to wade through them to get to the include guard? (re Peter Wood's comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Doxygen information about the Header file

Unless your boss does not say otherwise, it sincerely does not matter whether you put the comments before or after the include guards. It all depends on your (and your team's) personal preferences.
I usually put them at the beginning of the file.

### Doxygen information about the namespace

This is a little bit different, in this case you should always put them in front of the namespace, as it makes it more clear when someone reads the header.
You should always place the doxygen information before the documented elements.